# ADFS role when not member of AD group

Tags: adfs

Can anyone help me with the following - i need to set up some ADFS based on AD groups.

I can setup so i send af role/group based on AD group and that works fine, but i also need to check if a user is in some specific AD groups, and send a general role in my ADFS output, but only for people who are not member of specific groups.

Thanks in advance,
Mikael

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of your use case but you can have a number of menberOf rules all producing the same temporary claim.

Then use NOT EXISTS on that temporary claim to produce the claim you want.

So this claim will only apply to people who are not members of these groups.

Refer [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/adfs-claims-rules-c8e877faf352).